# How to simply share and synhronise a folder on two Ubuntu computers over home network

Tags: networking, file-sharing

Goal: To synchronise a folder, say pictures or documents ("sharefolder") on two computers on a home network, when both are running Ubuntu. (I have changed my initial question after having done some more research)

In version 20.04, I used the Nautilus GUI "Local network share" to "**share**" my "sharefolder". The first time I did that, a popup offered to install Samba. I accepted.

I would then open files (Nautilus) > "Other locations" > connect to server > smb://*ip-address*. I would use Unison for the synchronising part.

From Hirsute Hippo, I can now open "sharefolder" on Focal Fossa, but Focal Fossa cannot open "sharefolder" in Hirsute Hippo."Permission denied". Why?

Samba is intended mainly for sharing with Windows. There are various options for sending a file from one Ubuntu computer to another over a local network e.g. Wormhole, Teleport, Warpinator. But as far as I know they don't enable synchronising.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This may be UFW blocking Samba. From a Terminal, try this:

```
sudo ufw allow Samba
```

You can also verify which applications and ports are allowed through the firewall with `sudo ufw status verbose`, which will give you something like:

```
to                        action      from
--                        ------      ---
...
53 (Samba)                ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
88 (Samba)                ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
135/tcp (Samba)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
137/udp (Samba)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
138/udp (Samba)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
139/tcp (Samba)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
389 (Samba)               ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
445/tcp (Samba)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
464 (Samba)               ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
636/tcp (Samba)           ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
1024:5000/tcp (Samba)     ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
3268/tcp (Samba)          ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
3269/tcp (Samba)          ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
5353 (Samba)              ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. At the moment I only have one of the computers with me, the Hippo. But I see that your suggestion to run "$ sudo ufw status verbose" returns: "status inactive" (and I read that "by default UFW is disabled". I guess that indicates that the ufw is not the culprit here, does it not?